# удержание клавиши клавиатуры на время

Tags: python, клавиатура, pyautogui, ahk

Пишу бота, для игры нужно удержание клавиши в периоде 1 секунды.
Я пробовал библиотеки *ahk pyautogui keyboard* однако не получается зажать клавишу.

```
import pyautogui
import time
pyautogui.keyDown("a")  # pressing down key 'a'
time.sleep(1)  # how ever long you want
pyautogui.keyUp("a")  # stop pressing key 'a' down
```

однако при проверки клавиша нажимается единажды (не спамится типпо аааааааа)

Comment: Что мешает нажимать в цикле?

Comment: я считаю что античит распознает это макросом ,помимо этого игрой задумывается что не нужно кликать а следует удерживать

Comment: Нормальное нажатие это последовательность KeyDown, KeyUp, KeyDown посылает один скан-код, KeyUp посылает другой скан-код, если посылать только KeyDown то как раз получается зажатие клавиши. А античит если умный, все равно определит кнопкадав.

Comment: Я пытался справиться таким образом .В моем понимании должен получиться спам одной буквы но получается лишь одна. Как я понял это не предназначено для моей цели а скорее для комбинаций клавиш

Comment: К сожелению или счастью, но ни одна библиотека по нажиманию кнопок вам не поможет. Даже если вы будите генерировать нажатие через апи системы(самостоятельно), игра легко и без проблем определит что это эмуляция;))